# how to generate sound in the expo or any way to access web audio API in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

how to generate sound in the expo or any way to access web audio API in the expo? i want to create a morse code sound producing app (beep sound)

Answer (score 0):

**For Expo SDK 44;**

Use the Audio component from `expo-av`.

See the sample usage from Expo docs for an example:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/

Simply export all Morse code character sounds in a directory under assets (ideally) and assign them as you would like in your code.

Here's a wiki folder full of all Morse code sounds in case you need those.
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Audio_files_of_Morse_code